# Select and warp group of elements in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I got the following code:

```
<div class="timeline">
    <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
    <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
    <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
    <div class="empty-timeslice"></div>
    <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
    <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
    <div class="empty-timeslice"></div>
    <div class="empty-timeslice"></div>
    <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
    <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
    <div class="timeslice" data-tid="361"></div>
    <div class="timeslice" data-tid="361"></div>
</div>
```

I want to warp the divs by group of same attribute and in the same "group", like so:

```
<div class="timeline">
    <div class="warp">
        <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
        <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
        <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
   </div>
        <div class="empty-timeslice"></div>
   </div>
    <div class="warp">
        <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
        <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
   </div>
    <div class="empty-timeslice"></div>
    <div class="empty-timeslice"></div>
    <div class="warp">
        <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
        <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
   </div>
    <div class="warp">
        <div class="timeslice" data-tid="361"></div>
        <div class="timeslice" data-tid="361"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In my code, I am able to get each value of data-tid, like so:

```
function warpAroundTimeslice(arrayOfTid){
   ...
}
```

Any ideas?

if I put in another way I am trying to **select the elements with same class/attribute that are next to each other** in order to warp them

I hope my question makes sense, if not please let me know!
Thanks a lot!

---

Thanks to Leonardo Delfino, here is the final code, which works for me:

```
 var group = [];    
 var groupCount = 0;
 var group_attr_value = '360';

 $(".timeline > div").each(function(i, item) {
  var $item = $(item);
  if($item.attr('data-tid') == group_attr_value) {
       group.push(item);
  };

  if($item.next().attr('data-tid') != group_attr_value) {
       $(group).wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'> Comment: " + groupCount + "</div>");
       group = [];
       groupCount++;        
  }       
  });
```

Comment: forgot to past "Hello" at the top of my question: Hello!

Comment: thanks Sebsemillia ;)
I could ask my question in another way: **"Selecting all the elements with same class/attribute that are next to each other"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var group = [];    
var groupCount = 0;
var group_class = "timeslice";

$(".timeline > div").each(function(i, item) {
    var $item = $(item);
    if($item.hasClass(group_class)) {
        group.push(item);
    };

    if(group.length > 0 && !$item.next().hasClass(group_class)) {        
        $(group).wrapAll("<div class='wrap'> Group: " + groupCount + "</div>");
        group = [];
        groupCount++;        
    }       
});
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wv9W7/3/

Comment: The code groups the items only by the class, you need only modify the function to also group by data-tid

Answer (score 0):

You could go about this several ways. If you don't mind the elements being wrapped individually (instead of grouped like in your example), then a simple solution would be:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv9W7/)**

JS:

```
$('.timeslice').wrap('<div class="wrap">');
```

Comment: unfortunately, it won't work for me. my aim is to add container around a group to add a comment per group like so:
`<div class="warp">
        <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
        <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
        <div class="timeslice" data-tid="360"></div>
<p>this is the first group of timeslice</p>
   </div>`